# MongoDB Shell code for left join recursive in one collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

### What are the details of your problem?

I have a two colletions called `nodes` and `organisations`.

#### Problem 1: left join for same collection

In `nodes` there is an attribute called `kind`, there are three kinds A,B,C, and each kinds have slightly different schema, in A, there is `_b` attribute which link to B's object ID: `_id`, in B, `_c` object ID link to other collection `organisations`.

#### Problem 2: left join recursively

In `organisations`'s C, there is a `_parentOrg` ObjectID which link to another document in `organisations` and I don't know how many parent it have, so need do it recursively.

### What did you try and what were you expecting?

I tried with `$lookup` but that is only for two collections, not for one collection.

### Minimal reproducible example:

collection:`nodes`:

A:

```json
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "53a7892a0c4ec9a238378c30"
    },
    "_b": {
      "$oid": "54fe2bf27dab2fd24e61e26b"
    },
    "serial": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "kind": "A type",
    "name": "A123",
    "active": true,
    "createdDate": {
      "$date": "2014-06-23T01:55:54Z"
    }
  }
```

B:

```json
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "54fe2bf27dab2fd24e61e26b"
    },
    "_c": "5f0b9d810e170b6f2337073d",
    "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY",
    "kind": "Factory",
    "name": "L University",
    "active": true,
    "isTemplateSite": false,
    "createdDate": {
      "$date": "2015-03-09T23:25:38Z"
    },
     "address": {
      "suburb": "CFD",
      "city": "XXX city",
      "country": {
        "$oid": "5398fa6e2d764afe32a29aac"
      },
      "street": "21 New ave"
    },
  }
```

---

collection:`organisations`:

C:

```json
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f0b9d810e170b6f2337073d"
    },
    "name": "SPIP",
    "_parentOrg": {
      "$oid": "5702f5161c852788280926f3"
    },
    "_country": {
      "$oid": "5398fa6e2d764afe32a29aac"
    },
    "isNotBillable": false,
  }
```

C1:

```json
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5702f5161c852788280926f3"
    },
    "name": "KJSLKDJ LTD",
    "_parentOrg": null,(or no such attribute)
    "_country": {
      "$oid": "5398fa6e2d764afe32a29aac"
    },
    "isNotBillable": true,
  }
```

**NOTE: some time you there are only two layers no `_parentOrg` or `_parentOrg=null` then stop**

### Expected

I want to do some join like enrich A with B, then enrich the result from previous with C(and C's parents if possible) by left join. Also there are some duplicated attributed in A,B,C, like `name`, after the whole join, I want something like `{A.name, B.name, C.name, C1.name}`, I'd like keep everything without project, but the resutl need easy to differentiate which attribute from A or B or C.

Comment: What have you tried?  How is it insufficient?  Is there an error?  What's the error message?

Comment: Here's a [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q1vXlZ5rnkP) to get you started.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, your method works. Thx!!